# Android GridView fit to x y of relative layout

Tags: android, gridview

I write this xml code to show the gridview on the image background:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageDown"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/down" 
            android:visibility="gone"/>

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/grid"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:columnWidth="150dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="@+id/imageDown"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:numColumns="auto_fit"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth">

        </GridView>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_weight="9"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </RelativeLayout>
```

but when I run the my app show the image background and `GridView` on the background image,but `GridView`not fitXY to background image,some time larger than background and some time lower than image background.

Comment: you have to be more clear what are you asking for...

Comment: my friend,my app when run gridview some time big than background and some time lower

Comment: @Prag'sシ thanks gor pay attention to my problem my dear friend!

Comment: use `android:scaleType="fitXY"` in imageview..